# Azure devops server (on premise) integrate with SourceTree or Gitkraken

Tags: azure, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree, gitkraken, azure-devops-server-2019

I've recently setup an azure devops server on a VM but I can't seem to connect to it using Gitkraken. GitKraken will give the error "Could not reach the specified host domain"

SourceTree will give an error "TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required"

I used devops.ourdomain.com/MyCollection on sourcetree/gitkraken to try and connect. I tried it with the /MyCollection and without.

On IIS Anonymous Authentication is enabled, and so is Windows authentication.
Currently the devops environment is not connected to our AD but authentication is done through local windows accounts on the VM.

Are there any settings on the server that I'm possibly missing? The Devops environment is only reachable when you are connected to our VPN, so maybe that could be the issue?

Connecting through Visual Studio directly does work

Answer (score 1):

Regarding GitKraken: The Azure DevOps integration is intended for hosted instances only. There is an active feature request to support on premises Azure DevOps Server instances.

https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/184569/azure-devops-server-integration